# If the normalization is affine, is it affine? (if quasiaffine)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, normalization, separation-axioms

I was surprised to [find out](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0271) that, even if the normalization $X^\nu$ of a scheme $X$ is affine, $X$ may not be affine (remove the line $x=y$ from their example to make the source affine). In the example I'm working on, both $X$ and $X^\nu$ are quasi-affine. In fact $X \to \text{Spec }A$ is a quasi-affine open of affine space $\mathbb{A}^k_A \to \text{Spec }A$ and so $X^\nu$ is the pullback of the normalization of $\text{Spec }A$. Does it follow then that if $X^\nu$ is affine, so is $X$?

Comment: Have you seen [Tag 01YQ](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01YQ)? (I apologize that I haven't read through Tag 0271.)

Comment: Thank you so much! I was trying to do a Leray Spectral Sequence argument that was a waste of time, and the stacks project tag I found made me nervous it was false.

Comment: For the record, the Tag 01YQ result is also EGA II, (6.7.1) and is due to Chevalley in the case of algebraic schemes. For a non-noetherian generalization see [Tag 05YQ](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05YQ). I believe I have seen a generalization to algebraic spaces but can't remember where.

Comment: Correction to previous comment: the non-noetherian case is [Tag 05YU](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05YU), not 05YQ.